# Cannot install web3 node module

Tags: ethereum, web3js

As per the documentation, `npm install web3` would install the library but when I am trying to install the module it is throwing the following error:

```
PS F:\Sportist> npm install web3
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Users\aayush.thakur\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: read error: Invalid argument
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aayush.thakur\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-01T07_46_08_899Z-debug.log
```

complete log: [link](https://pastebin.com/7Wg3HTMV)

Comment: Try it on cmd not on powershell

Comment: Getting the same error on cmd.

Comment: Have you completely uninstalled node and npm and reinstalled?

Comment: Can you please make sure you have Git installed at the correct location and share the error log?

Comment: Git is installed and exported via environment variables, error log added.

Comment: Can you please try installing `npm install websocket` then try installing web3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add git config by executing the command: `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

This git config will change `git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git` to `https://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git`